# How can I get a status code of a response in graphql-yoga?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

I use [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga) for my graphql server and I want to extract a status code under `formatResponse`:

```
  Query: {
    get_foo: () => {
      return fetch(URL).then(res => res.json());
    },
```

```
const options = {
  ...
  // A function applied to each response after execution
  formatResponse,
};
```

```
const formatResponse = (res) => {
   console.log(res);
};
```

I tried to print both `res, req` but the response (`res`) doesn't store a status code field.